Use init SQL script in C# WPF apps
I've got a WPF application and i want to apply some init sql script in order to full some table.
In my all project solution i've got one project for the application and one SQLProject to make compare when i modify the tables.
i've put my sql script in the SQLProject folder, but how can i call them into my base application ?

i tried to add my SQL project in dll reference but i don't have any proposition with using completion.

Is your question how to run sql-file? I guess using relative path to sql-file will work locally.

yes but my sql file is into other project so the question is how to run it with the correct path

Take absolute path of sql-file, e.g. c:\projects\solution\project A\file.sql, then take absolute path of exe-file, e.g. c:\projects\solution\project B\bin\debug\b.exe, find root folder, which is "c:\projects\solution". Go up from exe file to this folder and then go down to reach sql-file: "..\..\..\..\" + "project A\file.sql". That's the correct relative path. You can make it absolute. Also related.

Include the SQL files as resource in a C# project.

ok but in production computer, i guess i'll not have my sql project right ?

Set the Build Action of the script files to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy always or Copy if newer. Then they will also be copied to the output directory of the application that references the library project.
